# Debug with F5 fails on VSCode saying "Unable to establish a connection to GDB"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, g++, mingw

When I press F5 key to run a C++ program on Visual Studio Code, I get the message

`"Unable to start debugging. Unable to establish a connection to GDB. Debug output may contain more information."`

I use `g++.exe` and MinGW for compiling.
Until an hour ago, the debugging with F5 key was done properly, and I've never touched `launch.json`. Could you tell me what is wrong?

Below is the `launch.json`

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - アクティブ ファイルのビルドとデバッグ",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "gdb の再フォーマットを有効にする",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe アクティブなファイルのビルド"
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is the `tasks.json`

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe アクティブなファイルのビルド",
            "command": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "コンパイラ: C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe アクティブなファイルのビルド ver(1)",
            "command": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "デバッガーによって生成されたタスク。"
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is the `c_cpp_properties.json`

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${vcpkgRoot}/x86-windows-static/include",
                "C:\\Users\\SonicTheHedgehog\\Desktop\\include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Addition:
I found an error message on `launch.json`

`Property console is not allowed`

and `console` is marked with wavy line.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Check out this link: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2889

There is some problem with PowerShell being run as in internal console (running within VSCode).

I made the following change in launch.json:

before:

```
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": **false**,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
```

after:

```
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": **true**,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
```

Now, I see the output of the program in cmd.exe outside VSCode. But, the debugger runs fine inside VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a different compiler-based extension such as code runner etc, sometimes, extensions are compatibility issues in visual studio code. I faced the same problem when I started to use visual studio code.

Comment: Thank you. The reason I chose this C/C++ extension is just  I'm not good at IT and it seems the community is big with a plenty of information .  Is "code runner" simple enough for beginners to use?

Comment: From my personal experience code runner is always good to use in MAC OS. on the other hand, if you use windows OS, I prefer to recommend visual studio 2019.